# Connecting to a JSON API in iOS that requires a user name and password

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa

I have a URL that when typed into a browser (EG Safari) requests a username and password, the response API comes back in the form of JSON.

Now I'm trying to connect to this API in my iOS app so I can work with the JSON data and I'm not sure if I'm going about it the correct way.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&Username=%@&Password=%@",@"username",@"password"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"jsonURL"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(connection)
{
   NSLog(@"connection success");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"connection could not be made");
}
```

The NSLog is coming back with a "connection success" response. However, I can't seem to load the JSON response into an NSDictionary or NSArray. I've used NSJSONSerialization here.

```
NSMutableData *urlData;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

urlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSLog(@"DID RECEIVE RESPONSE %@", urlData);
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {

[urlData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"FINISHED LOADING DATA %@", connection);

    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;

    NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

    if (jsonParsingError) {
    NSLog(@"JSON ERROR: %@", [jsonParsingError localizedDescription]);
}   else {
    NSLog(@"Parsed Object is %@", parsedObject);
  }

}
```

And here is my JSON error from the NSLog: "JSON ERROR: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)"

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this `NSString *strRes = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` please `NSLog` this string and add it in question so we may know that you got proper response or not.so we can help you.

Comment: In your didFinishLoading method just check for the response as NSString like `NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);`

Comment: I'm getting invalid username and password. However both are correct as they work in the browser. On the browser I'm being asked for the username and password via an input Login popup. So I think the problem is with the format of the post: NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&Username=%@&Password=%@",@"username",@"password"];

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *jsonstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"userName\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\",\"loginFrom\":\"2\",\"loginIp\":\"%@\"}",[username_text removequotes],[password_text removequotes],ipaddress];//The removeQuotes method is used to escape sequence the " to \" so that the json structure won't break. If the user give " in the username or password field and if we dint handle that the json structure will break and may give an expection.
NSLog(@"the json string we are sending is %@",jsonstring);
NSData *strdata = [json1  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *fixedURL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",loginURL];//the url is saved in loginURL variable.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fixedURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: strdata];
conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (conn) {
    NSLog(@"Connected to service waiting for response");
}
```

Example code for login using json web services

Comment: Can you be more specific? As in what are the methods "removequotes", "removeEnter" and loginEndpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved this. Use:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
    NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username"
                                                                password:@"password"
                                                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    NSLog(@"credential created");
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"previous authentication failure");
}


}
```

You actually don't need to set request values (e.g.: [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];) etc etc

Connect with a:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and handle the JSON response data with:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

urlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSLog(@"DID RECEIVE RESPONSE");
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {

NSLog(@"THE RAW DATA IS %@", data);
[urlData appendData:data];

NSString *strRes = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"LOGGING THE DATA STRING %@", strRes);

}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSLog(@"FINISHED LOADING DATA %@", connection);

NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
//id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
NSArray *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);


if (jsonParsingError) {
    NSLog(@"JSON ERROR: %@", [jsonParsingError localizedDescription]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"PARSED OBJECT %@", parsedObject);

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) whenever deal with networking.

```
[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:username
                                                          password:password];
```